# Heating up using an LM317 voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I try to regulate a 12V into 3.7V using an  LM317 voltage regultor.

I used R1=220Ohm and R2=470Ohm, using this circuit:

[image: this diagram]

It regulates a 3.9V (close enough for me,) but it heats up. I can't even touch it while it is powering an ESP8266 ( which draws a max of 200mA.)

Why is it getting hot?

Comment: You have to put a heatsink on it, or use a lower input voltage.

Comment: Use a switching buck/step down regulator.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I need to use a 12v power supply to light up a led strip. Using 2 power sources is not an option

Comment: Then use a switching regulator module or add a heat sink to dissipate all your wasted energy from using a linear regulator.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany can you please ref ?

Comment: "*... can you please ref ?*" Please note that product recommendations are off-topic. You can't ask. See the help section linked below.

Comment: @Transistor I can't understand why, since I'm talking on a specific product I use, and as a part of the solution, another product is recommended ( which are vast in characteristic ).

Comment: @Guy.D reflate? reforest? As transistor says product recommendations are off topic, particularly finished products like modules where the design has already been completed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, sorry but I did not understand the first part of your comment. I'm  trying understand a better path to walk, looking for a "switching regulator module" (perhaps it is some kind of a lead ), does not coherently point for something I can start with... but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, under the conditions you are using the regulator, it will heat up a lot, as it is a linear regulator. It will dissipate all excess power as heat.

Since the voltage over the regulator input and output is about 8V, and the maximum current draw is about 0.2A, the regulator will have to dissipate maximum of 1.6W as heat.

The junction to ambient thermal resistance is about 25 degrees C/W, so as an extremely crude approximation, chip case can be approximated to be about 40 degrees higher than ambient room temperature.